# Error persists~ "fullscreen_content_controls cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm kind of a noob android developer, and I hit a few bumps while trying to create a button that opens a new layout. While I was doing that, I got a few errors that would not go away no matter what I tried. In response, I copied most of the xml files and java files that I had changed from the original structure, and I added them to a new project, thinking all my errors would go away. I really need some help, I can't tell you how long I have been stuck on this small error. I have attached the main FullScreenActivity.java, activity_main.xml, the Android Manifest, and the error messages. Thank you in advance for the help guys, I really do appreciate it! c:

FullScreenActivity.java ~

```
package sehej.android.doge;
import sehej.android.doge.util.SystemUiHider;
import sehej.android.doge.R;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ****    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    ****    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });
        };

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml ~

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grass"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:padding="20sp"
    app:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <requestFocus
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        app:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        app:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        app:text="@string/button2"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        app:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        app:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        app:text="@string/button3"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        app:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        app:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        app:onClick="whenClicked"
        app:text="@string/button1"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        app:id="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        app:paddingBottom="30sp"
        app:text="@string/title"
        app:textColor="@color/blue"
        app:textSize="60sp"
        app:textStyle="bold"
        app:typeface="sans" />
```

Android Manifest ~

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sehej.android.doge"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="sehej.android.doge.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error messages from problems view ~

fullscreen_content_controls cannot be resolved or is not a field    FullscreenActivity.java /???/src/sehej/android/doge
line 54 Java Problem

fullscreen_content cannot be resolved or is not a field FullscreenActivity.java /???/src/sehej/android/doge 
line 55 Java Problem

```
~~~~??? is the project/application name
~~~~I have marked the section that received the errors with '***'s
```

Comment: Can you mention line no 55 in your java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined

```
fullscreen_content_controls
fullscreen_content
```

The above id in your `activity_main.xml` Thats why you are getting

> fullscreen_content_controls cannot be resolved or is not a field FullscreenActivity.java .

As looking at your code you have not declare any `View` with the id

`fullscreen_content_controls`

`fullscreen_content` in your `activity_main.xml`.

If you want to get rid of this problem you have to define two `Views` with the id you are mentioning in your code.

**Edit**

you will usually call `setContentView(int)` with a layout resource defining your UI, and using `findViewById(int)` to retrieve the widgets in that UI So whatever view you have declared in your Ui Xml you can get those.

Like in your case you have defined button so something like

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

will work for you now you can use this widget in your application.

Comment: So I need to create two "<View/>"s in my activity_main.xml? Im having a hard time understanding why it is necessary to do so, could you explain a bit more and show a little about how it would look? Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: I still don't completely understand, what would I change in my xml file? And how do I make the java file correct also. I appreciate the edit, but it all sounds foreign to me, I don't understand what to change... :(

Comment: What is the purpose of the `View` in your `UI`? Why you are using this? Without knowing that how can we just write the code? Just define two `View` in your layout like you have defined Button simple.

Comment: Nevermind, It worked again after I tried it a second time, thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @frgnvola you can accept the answer if it helped you thanks. :-) And Without knowing why you are creating these view we can help you know that ... Any way happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve this problem I faced. It happens when you press ctrl+shift+O to auto import.
the solution is to 
Replace import android.R with .R in your activity java file.