# error :cannot find symbol variable fullscreen_content_controls,fullscreen_content and dummy_button

Tags: javascript, android, xml

`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="USERNAME"
    android:background="#9E9E9E"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="\NPASSWORD"
    android:background="#9E9E9E"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REGISTER"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="51dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SIGNIN"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="             \n           \n                             CBTT      \n \n"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" USERNAME \n"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
>\
```

`   ![I don't change any code in Java I don't know what's the issue][1]
    I have not used any code in Java don't  know what's the issue the above code is my layout xml
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y90xP.png

Comment: Where is the code? What you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I even have an error showing cannot find symbol variable dummy_button which i forgot to include please help me out

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: I am new to this field i was trying to build an app initially i just wrote an XML code which contain login page view i just thought to see it how it runs  in the emulator n i end up with these errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878255/error-persists-fullscreen-content-controls-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-fiel

Comment: sorry but i have already seen tht post but didnt understand so i had to post here